# User inserting data into Google Calender PHP

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I have an embedded calender on my site and I am looking to allow the users to add events to the calender, how would I go about this with PHP?

I have looked at the Google API document but cannot understand how to implement their example, see below:

```
$calendarListEntry = new CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId("calendarId");

$createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);

echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

At the moment my code looks like this;

```
<?php 
  require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
  require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
  $calendarListEntry = new CalendarListEntry();
  $calendarListEntry->setId("cdnavechicleservices@gmail.com");
  $createdCalendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
  echo $createdCalendarListEntry->getSummary();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out how to use this but I was able to do what I wanted plus more using Zend Gdata.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html